# Error in R about plot.new hasn't been called yet

Tags: r, plot

I have this code and it's giving the following error. I searched but found no answer.

```
par(mar=c(10,6,6,6))
grid(nx = 24, ny = 8, col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted")
porcentagem_sem_rep<-c(18.08, 8.73, 8.53, 8.33, 6.91, 6.70, 5.89, 4.67, 4.47, 3.45, 3.25, 3.04, 2.64, 2.43, 2.23, 2.23, 1.82, 1.82, 1.42, 1.01, 1.01, 0.60, 0.40, 0.20)
#calcular as porcentagens e inserir manualmente sem o símbolo criando um vetor como feito acima
plot(porcentagem_sem_rep,ylim=c(0,20),xaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="Exposição na mídia (%)",pch=19)
axis(side=1,at=1:24,labels=c("Fazenda","Educação","Relações Exteriores","Justiça","Trabalho","Casa Civil","Esporte","Saúde","Transporte","Defesa","Planejamento","Minas e Energia","Comunicações","Integração","Turismo","Cidades","Pesca","Desenvolvimento","Relações Institucionais","Agricultura", "Previdência", "Cultura", "Meio Ambiente", "Ciência"),las=3)
```

**The error**

> Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
>     plot.new has not been called yet

Comment: From `?grid` you can read: `grid adds an nx by ny rectangular grid to an existing plot.` So you need to have a plot before adding a grid, since you dont have any plot, R shows this error which tells you that it cannot find any plot to add a grid on it.

Comment: Just put `grid` as the **last** instruction.

Comment: Thank you, but the grid is now in front of the plot. How can i change it?